# Get the selected value from a programatically created RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET project I need to create a RadioButtonList for each column of a dynamically sized table. The table's dimensions are set via Web Service.
For this scenario I create a RadioButtonList in a loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
{
    //Create a RadioButtonList for each column/////////
      RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
      rbl.ID = "rbl" + j.ToString();
      rbl.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical;
```

The code works as intended, but for further processing I need to get the selected RadioButton's ID inside the RadioButtonList from outside the loop.
How do I have to do this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple By Creating a RadioButtonList by Global and add the Radiobutton inside the Loop.Then, It is Possible to get the selected Value Outside the loop